# Using java, input string="aabbcdeaaaabbb" and the output must be aaaa

Tags: java

Using java, input string="aabbcdeaaaabbb" and the output must be aaaa, as sequence here is having repeated 4 times a. Can anyone help me to get this "aaaa" as output using java implementation.

Algorithm to find the Longest substring having same character repeated.

for eg:

I/P: aabbcdefaaaacccccc  O/P: cccccc

Please check my program below and suggest any optimization for faster processing:

```
public class LongestSubString {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        System.in));
System.out
        .println("Enter a word to find longest substring with same characters repeated");
String word = reader.readLine();

System.out.println("Entered word is: " + word);

System.out.println("Longest repeated characters substring is: "
        + subStringFinder(word));

}

/*
*longest substring finder with same character repeated
*/

public static String subStringFinder(String word) {
char[] tokens = word.toCharArray();
int len = tokens.length;
int wordLen = word.length();

System.out.println("len of input word: " + wordLen);

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder strConcat = new StringBuilder("");
for (int j = 0; j <= len - 1; j++) {

    if (j + 1 > len - 1) {
        if ((strConcat.length() >= 1)
                && (strConcat.charAt(strConcat.length() - 1) == (tokens[j]))) {
            strConcat.append("" + tokens[j]);
            myList.add(strConcat.toString());
        }
    }

    else {
        if (tokens[j] == tokens[j + 1]) {
            if ((strConcat.length() >= 1)
                    && (strConcat.charAt(strConcat.length() - 1) == (tokens[j]))) {
                strConcat.append("" + tokens[j]);
                myList.add(strConcat.toString());
            } else {
                strConcat = new StringBuilder("");
                strConcat.append("" + tokens[j]);
            }
        } else {
            if ((strConcat.length() >= 1)
                    && (strConcat.charAt(strConcat.length() - 1) == (tokens[j]))) {
                strConcat.append("" + tokens[j]);
                myList.add(strConcat.toString());
            } else {
                strConcat = new StringBuilder("");
                strConcat.append("" + tokens[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int max = 0, index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    String strEle = myList.get(i);
    int strLen = strEle.length();

    if (max < strLen) {
        max = strLen;
        index = i;
    }

}

return myList.get(index);

}
}
```

Comment: "aabbcdeaaaabbb".substring(7, 11)

Comment: @ekaerovets - thats just general example string I provided. My question is, in a string finding the longest substring with only repeated characters, as in this case its "aaaa".

Comment: @Arafath - you'd better specify this in the question.
You should iterate through the string, keep current length of the substring with the same characters, keep max length, and the repeating character itself. 500 chars (comment length) isn't enough for the code.

Comment: I hope its clear now Sanjeev and vipin cp. please do check and can this be unmarked as "on hold"

Comment: @Sanjeev please check and can u please remove the put on hold flag from this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code is overly complicated. You don’t need a `StringBuilder` nor an `ArrayList`. I tried to understand your intention, but then skipped it and wrote my own version instead. Hope it helps anyway.

```
public static String subStringFinder(String word) {
    if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) {
        return word;
    }
    char currentChar = word.charAt(0);
    int longestStart = 0;
    int longestLength = 0;
    int currentStart = 0;
    int currentLength = 1;
    for (int ix = 1; ix < word.length(); ix++) {
        if (word.charAt(ix) == currentChar) {
            currentLength++;
        } else {
            if (currentLength > longestLength) {
                longestStart = currentStart;
                longestLength = currentLength;
            }
            currentChar = word.charAt(ix);
            currentStart = ix;
            currentLength = 1;
        }
    }
    if (currentLength > longestLength) {
        longestStart = currentStart;
        longestLength = currentLength;
    }
    return word.substring(longestStart, longestStart + longestLength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String in = "aabbcdeaaaabbb"; 
String t; 
ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>(); 
String l="";
int c=0; 
String n; 

  for(int i=0;i<in.length;i++) { 
     n=in.substring(i, i+1); //get the current character 
     if(n.equals(l)){ 
        l=n; c++; 
      } 
    else { 
       t=n; 
       for(int j=1;j<c;j++) { 
           n+=t;
        }
    c=0; 
    out.add(n); 
    c=0; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I've deleted the useless text from the bottom of your answer and accepted your reformatting. Can you add some explanation of what the OP's problem was and how your code fixes it?